# How to receive a true false if an innertext exist in dom

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any dom javascript query which can give if a specific innerText exist in the dom.?

Example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('section.active div.test')[1].innerText('specific text') !== 0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: `.innerText.contains('specific text')` or `indexOf('specific text') > -1`

Comment: `innerText` is just a string.  Any method that will work on a string, will work on innerText as well

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("specific text") !== -1` if you want to check in the whole page, but if you have a specific element you're looking at, it would be faster.

Comment: `contains('specific text')` is your fighter

Comment: Do you want to know if the text just exists or what element contains that text?

Answer (score 1):

- Use [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- Use [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```js
const hasText = (el, text) => el.textContent.includes(text);

const div = document.querySelectorAll('section.active div.test')[1]
console.log(hasText(div, "specific text"));
```

```html
<section class="active">
  <div class="test">I am a DIV</div>
  <div class="test">I have a specific text!</div>
</section>
```

To loop all your elements use [NodeList.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

```js
const hasText = (el, text) => el.textContent.includes(text);

document.querySelectorAll('section.active div.test').forEach(el => {
  console.log(hasText(el, "specific text"));
});
```

```html
<section class="active">
  <div class="test">I am a DIV</div>
  <div class="test">I have a specific text!</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check an element's innertext for some specific text as follows:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('section.active div.test')[1].innerText).indexOf('specific text') > -1) {
// some code here
}
```